# Is there a way to generate and show Unique ID in Google Form?

Tags: spreadsheet

So, i have made a unique ID generated in a linked spread sheet using this formula.
 `=arrayformula( if( len(A2:A), "" & text(row(A2:A) - row(A2) + 2, "000") & RIGHT(VALUE(A2:A), 3), iferror(1/0) ) )`

but is there a way to pop it out in the google form? like a message with the unique ID come out at the last page so the responder can know their unique ID number and then use it for other purpose?

i want to use the unique number in a series of google forms without having to collect their emails. my plan is for responder to do the first google form and get the unique ID. Then use that id in other google form.

[Pre-play where the Output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th5DJ.png)

[Post-play where the Input is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz8vP.png)

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but is there a way to pop it out in the google form? like a message with the unique ID come out at the last page so the responder can know their unique ID number and then use it for other purpose?`?

Comment: so, what i want to make is not like a popout message. i just want to somehow call the random unique ID generated in the spreadsheet into a Question or something in the google form. like, there's a Question saying here is your Unique ID. --#####-- please take note.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `i just want to somehow call the random unique ID generated in the spreadsheet into a Question or something in the google form.`, in this case, when a user opens Google Form, you want to add a unique ID to one of several Questions in Google Form. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, you're correct. what i want is to just add the unique ID to one of the questions as an identifier so that i can use it to compare the analysis with other google form

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I might be able to understand your direction. In order to correctly imagine your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image? By this, I would like to think of the sample script for achieving your goal.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have put the the sample output and input in the question above. in the form of screenshot of the pre-play and post-play survey.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the images. From your additional images, unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to think of the solution by correctly understanding your goal. I apologize for this.